# Get row with max value in Hive/SQL?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm new to Hive/SQL, and I'm stuck on a fairly simple problem. My data looks like:

```
+------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| carrier_iD |     meandelay      |     meancanceled      |
+------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| EV         | 13.795802119653473 | 0.028584251044292006  |
| VX         | 0.450591016548463  | 2.364066193853424E-4  |
| F9         | 10.898001378359766 | 0.00206753962784287   |
| AS         | 0.5071547420965062 | 0.0057404326123128135 |
| HA         | 1.2031093279839498 | 5.015045135406214E-4  |
| 9E         | 8.147899230704216  | 0.03876067292247866   |
| B6         | 9.45383857757506   | 0.003162096314343487  |
| UA         | 8.101511665305816  | 0.005467725574605967  |
| FL         | 0.7265068895709532 | 0.0041141513746490044 |
| WN         | 7.156119279121648  | 0.0057419058192869415 |
| DL         | 4.206288692245839  | 0.005123990066804269  |
| YV         | 6.316802855264404  | 0.029304029304029346  |
| US         | 3.2221527095063736 | 0.007984031936127766  |
| OO         | 6.954715814690328  | 0.02596499362466706   |
| MQ         | 9.74568222216328   | 0.025628100708354324  |
| AA         | 8.720522654298968  | 0.019242775597574157  |
+------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

I want Hive to return the row with the meanDelay max value. I have:

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(meandelay) as FLOAT) FROM flightinfo;
```

which indeed returns the max (I use cast because my values are saved as STRING). So then:

```
SELECT * FROM flightinfo WHERE meandelay = (SELECT CAST(MAX(meandelay) AS FLOAT) FROM flightinfo);
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:44 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'cast' '(' in expression specification
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the [windowing and analytics functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)

```
SELECT carrier_id, meandelay, meancanceled
FROM
 (SELECT carrier_id, meandelay, meancanceled,
         rank() over (order by cast(meandelay as float) desc) as r 
  FROM table) S 
WHERE S.r = 1;
```

This will also solve the problem if more than one row has the same max value, you'll get all the rows as result. If you just want a single row change `rank()` to `row_number()` or add another term to the `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

use join instead.

```
SELECT a.* FROM flightinfo a left semi join  
(SELECT CAST(MAX(meandelay) AS FLOAT)  
maxdelay FROM flightinfo)b on (a.meandelay=b.maxdelay)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `collect_max` UDF from Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) to solve this problem, passing in a value of 1, meaning that you only want the single max value.

```
select array_index( map_keys( collect_max( carrier_id, meandelay, 1) ), 0 ) from flightinfo;
```

Also, I've read somewhere that the Hive `max` UDF does allow you to access other fields on the row, but I think its easier just to use `collect_max`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your sub-query is allowed ...

A quick look here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

states:

> As of Hive 0.13 some types of subqueries are supported in the WHERE
>   clause. Those are queries where the result of the query can be treated
>   as a constant for IN and NOT IN statements (called uncorrelated
>   subqueries because the subquery does not reference columns from the
>   parent query):

Comment: Oh... is there a practical way around this?