# SQL select only max count values for each group

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query like this:

```
select
  id,
  url,
  count(*) as count
from hit
where ...
group by
  id,
  url
```

There are unique ids that usually have multiple urls assigned to it but only one of these urls is correct (I assume that it is the one with max count). Therefore once I have the query results I would like to select only max count values for each id while keeping only the corresponding url. Is there a way to do this? Max(count) obviously not working..

Comment: You can rank the records using window functions and then select the top ranked for each `id`. An example of how to do this in Hive SQL can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20668100/2221001).

Comment: @JNevill Thanks, for completeness my solution is as follows: `rank() over (partition by category_id order by count desc) as r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I am not entirely sure either it should give you what you're expecting as you didn't give any sample data to work on. One point is : if there is duplicate maximum no of counts for a particular URL within an id, then the query should populate both the URLs as you didn't mention any logic which one to keep.

```
with make_cte as
(
    select id, url, count(*) as cnt
    from hit
    group by id, url
)
select id , url from
(
select id , url , cnt , max(cnt) over(partition by id) as max_cnt
from make_cte
) as a where cnt = max_cnt;
```